# Access Firebase user / DB between scenes?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating 2 scenes, one for authenticating the user with Firebase Auth, after successfull connection i go to an other scene, where I wan't to to access the UserId. How can I access the Firebase Service between scenes? Do i have to create a DoNotDestroy object and store my login script in there, or any other great solutions?

I tried transfering my login script with DoNotDestroy when changing to the DB scene, I can access currentUser etc but the DB does not work, no errors, but does not insert the data into the table. (Works as Standalone scenes but not when switched)

I am using the Unity Firebase Guide

I solved the initalization of the DB by the code below.
Now i can get information of the currently signed in user and do stuff in the database. The problem was is I had the same Awake() function in both scripts.

In FirebaseLogin.cs | Scene 1

```
public void Awake()
{
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("the_url");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("the_file.p12");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("the_email.com");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("the_pass");
    mDatabaseRef = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
}
```

Inside FirebaseDatabase.cs | Scene 2

```
void Awake()
{
    reference = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    myUser = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Hey!
I just solved the issue, i was initalizing it the wrong way, I'll edit the post and put the code in there.

Comment: @Corey, can you plz share your complete code of implementing userId access between scenes?